# Table for complaint storage statuses?

Tags: sap-erp, sap-dotnet-connector, sap-r3

I am trying to download SAP `QPRS` table to get a list of [Physical sample , Material number, batch & Physical sample status (sample was stored & sample exist)]. I am using SAP .Net Connector to call the function module `RFC_READ_TABLE` to read the table `QPRS`.

But I cannot find the screen fields `RQPRS-PRNVX` and `RQPRS-AUFBX` that are related to physical sample status. Is it a structure, if so, how can I use `RFC_READ_TABLE` function module to ready these data.

I know I can use function modules to get physical sample status, but this is done material by material, which is very slow. I now to get whole table contact once to make it faster.

NB. Data needed is into SAP Tcode `QPR3`, in "Sample Storage" tab:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flags are stored as statuses in the table `JEST`:

- Sample Was Stored: status `I0363` (short code in Status History: "STRD")
- Sample Consumed/Destroyed: status `I0362` (short code in Status History: "USED")

The table `JEST` has 3 important columns:

- OBJNR: "QP" followed with the sample number (12 digits, right-aligned, padded with zeroes on the left)
- STAT: status
- INACT: " " means that the status is set, "X" means that the status is not set

Comment: Hi Sandra, Excellent... Great... Thanks so much

Comment: one last thing. if i need to automatically change these fields, how can I do that using sap.net connector ?

Comment: You're asking for a RFC-enabled function module to update the table `JEST`. It's a completely different question, please ask a new one.

Comment: new question placed , ref   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60429968/rfc-enabled-function-module-to-update-the-table-jest