# RFC-enabled function module to update physical samples

Tags: sap-erp, saprfc, bapi, function-module

I need to update some fields of Physical samples in SAP ERP:

List of columns which are in the table `QPRS`:

- ABINF: Storage Information
- ABDAT: Storage Deadline
- ABORT: Storage Location

List of fields which correspond to statuses (table `JEST`):

- Sample Was Stored: status `I0363` (short code in Status History: "STRD")
- Sample Consumed/Destroyed: status `I0362` (short code in Status History: "USED")

Is there a RFC-enabled function module to update these fields?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried searching in SE37? [Looking Up Function Modules](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nwpi71/7.1/en-US/d1/801ec1454211d189710000e8322d00/content.htm?no_cache=true)

Comment: I do not have access to SE37

Comment: How is statuses related to storage data? They are written to `JEST` by system and not manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no BAPI for updating storage data. Anyhow but you will need ABAP development for this, **QPRS_QPRS_STORAGE_UPDATE** is the FM you can copy into Z one and make it remote-enabled:

```
DATA: i_qprs      TYPE qprs,
      i_lgort     TYPE qprs-lgort  VALUE 'Z07',
      i_abort     TYPE qprs-abort  VALUE '1',
      i_abdau     TYPE qprs-abdau  VALUE 10,
      i_abdat     TYPE qprs-abdat  VALUE '20200510',
      i_abinf     TYPE qprs-abinf  VALUE 'info 1st',
      i_aufbx     TYPE rqprs-aufbx VALUE 'first storage',
      i_prnvx     TYPE rqprs-prnvx VALUE abap_true,
      i_qprs_cust TYPE qprs_cust,
      e_qprs_new  TYPE qprs,
      e_aufbx     TYPE rqprs-aufbx,
      e_prnvx     TYPE rqprs-prnvx.

i_qprs-phynr = '000900000054'.

CALL FUNCTION 'QPRS_QPRS_STORAGE_UPDATE'
  EXPORTING
    i_qprs                 = i_qprs
    i_lgort                = i_lgort
    i_abort                = i_abort
    i_abdau                = i_abdau
    i_abdat                = i_abdat
    i_abinf                = i_abinf
    i_aufbx                = i_aufbx
    i_prnvx                = i_prnvx
    i_qprs_cust            = i_qprs_cust
  IMPORTING
    e_qprs_new             = e_qprs_new
    e_aufbx                = e_aufbx
    e_prnvx                = e_prnvx
  EXCEPTIONS
    sample_locked          = 1
    locking_error          = 2
    sample_not_found       = 3
    abort_not_found        = 4
    sample_already_changed = 5.
```